# codesynthesis - DOMDocument ambigious error

Tags: c++, codesynthesis

I am trying to use CodeSynthesis XSD for generating C++ headers using XML Schema I have. The Header are generated successfully but when it comes to compiling the code the error message pops up saying something like

```
DOMDocument ambigious error
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me well.
goto installation directotry of Code Synthesis, normally its in C: Drive, then goto

> CodeSynthesis XSD 4.0\include\xsd\cxx\tree\

Open

> serializations.txx

inside this file, replace every

> DOMDocument

with

> xercesc::DOMDocument